# Build a go project from source

Tags: build, go

How can I build a Go project from source, instead of using `go get domain.com/dir/project`? For example, instead of

`go get github.com/kr/godep`

I want to build from the source:

```
git clone https://github.com/kr/godep.git
cd godep
GOPATH=/tmp/godep go build
```

The commands above will result in

```
dep.go:4:2: cannot find package "code.google.com/p/go.tools/go/vcs" in any of:
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.2/libexec/src/pkg/code.google.com/p/go.tools/go/vcs (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/hanxue/Source/godep/godep/src/code.google.com/p/go.tools/go/vcs (from $GOPATH)
save.go:5:2: cannot find package "github.com/kr/fs" in any of:
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.2/libexec/src/pkg/github.com/kr/fs (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/hanxue/Source/godep/godep/src/github.com/kr/fs (from $GOPATH)
```

Note: go 1.2 is installed in /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.2 with a link from `/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.2/bin/go` to `/usr/local/bin/go`

Comment: You have to install all the dependencies like `code.google.com/p/go.tools/go/vcs` manually, set up `GOPATH` carefully  http://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/GOPATH

Comment: @hanxue Just curious, what's wrong with using go get?

Comment: @nemo Nothing's wrong, in fact that is the best way to build a go project. I want to build from source so that I can create a Homebrew formula

Comment: @hanxue Ah that explains it. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 6):

You need the GOPATH configured correctly. Sometimes a project doesn't have to be checked out in the "sub path" it expects, but often it does and certainly things that depend on it will expect to find it there. So instead of "go get" you can

```
mkdir -p /tmp/go/src
export GOPATH=/tmp/go
cd $GOPATH/src
mkdir -p github.com/kr/godep
cd github.com/kr/godep/..
git clone http://github.com/kr/godep.git
cd godep
go build
```

... now rinse and repeat for each dependency!

```
cd $GOPATH/src
mkdir -p code.google.com/p/
cd code.google.com/p
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/go.tools/
```

Yes, the vcs dependency was in "go.tools" and needed to be cloned with hg instead. It took a bit of web browsing to figure out. Okay, I think you can see why that's annoying to do by hand.

I'll leave the rest of the dependencies as an exercise for the reader, or you can just use "go get". :-)

A bonus tip that might be what you are really looking for: After checking out the first project, you can use "go get" in that directory to download the dependencies of the project. Sometimes if you have something that's not "go get'able" that's useful if the dependencies are.